# How to clear state when only refreshing the page for a DataTable

Tags: javascript, html, datatable, bootstrap-4, callback

For a datatable in a page: I want datatable to be refreshed with a clear state(no column order etc.), but if page opens up with pressing back button from a page, it should keep its state.

So far I have tried some ways, and they are:

1- Using **performance.nagivation.type**, but could not perform it in the way I need.

```
// Refresh page, and table with a clear state.
if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
     // some code here
}
// Back key pressed, load parameters and columns.
else if (performance.navigation.type == 2) {
    // some code here
}
```

2- Using **drawCallback** function, but it did not work as well as I presumed.

```
drawCallback: function() {
    if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
        table.state.clear();
    }
}
```

I am really confused and not able to understand what is going wrong here. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, actually I did it correct, but totally forgot about caching. When I refresh the page with ignoring the cache. It worked as I want.

```js
drawCallback: function() {
    // When page is refreshed, draw table with clear state.
    if (performance.navigation.type == 1)
        table.state.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({stateSave: false});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: stateSave has to be true due to pagination or ordering columns. All I need was a special case for refreshing the page, and I got it. Thanks.